# What is the syntax to import a javascript file into another file with ecmascript 6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

so I have the following :

`const config = require('./config');` I can't find out how to translate this into ecmascript 6.

I am converting an existing JS codebase to es6 and wish take advantage of the latest enhancements of J syntax.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The suggestion is to consider why you need this. It's already ES6 syntax (`const`). The use of `import` doesn't mean that you can benefit from 'enhancements', due to how native ES modules are implemented in Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import config from './config.js'
```

Link to Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import